# How to deal with One to One json loop?

Tags: java, json, jackson

There's a class "User" in my application with one atribute that's another user.
My problem is that user one has user two, and user two has user one, my loop isn't like what I'm finding everywhere where one class has a list of other who has a list of the first one. My loop can be writen like this:

```
{
    "name": "user1,
    "friend": {
        "name": "user2",
        "friend": {
            "name": "user1",
            "friend": {
                "name": "user2",
                "friend": ....
....
}
```

Comment: Another option would be, rather than including the whole `User` object, add a unique ID to each user, and then in the `friend` field, include only the `id` of the friend. This will eliminate the cyclic process, but will require a lookup/query for the `friend` using the `id`. If all this data is going to be stored in a database, it will likely have a unique ID anyway.

Comment: @loganrussell48 That's an exellent answer, I have done this way so far, but my front-end need the frien object so they can show him to the user. They're are kinda in a hurry.

Comment: In that case, first load the current user. Within that User, a list of `id`s of their friends should be stored. After that data is loaded, make a second call to the database, retrieving the friend like so: `db.findUserByID(currentUser.friends[i]);` Do that in a loop for each friend to retrieve them from the database. OR If you have the ability to make changes to the backend systems, you could make the original call fetch the friends by ID and return only the data to be shown in the UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in an **infinite loop** (Jackson – Bidirectional Relationships), for preventing this situation you can use several techniques

1 -Use @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference

2- Use @JsonIdentityInfo

3- Use @JsonView

4- Use @JsonIgnore

5- Use @JsonView

6- Use a Custom Serializer

This link might be useful

**[Jackson – Bidirectional Relationships](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)**