# How to properly handle request body with mutual oject references in REST Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have entities that have references to themselves, for example:

- `Client` has many `Properties`
- `Property` has many `Clients`

Returning list of `Properties` by `Client` id causes `StackOverflowError` because it keeps nesting `Properties` inside `Client` and so on.

How can I deal with nesting in the most proper / elegant way?

Service

```
    public Set<Home> getHouses(Long userId) {
        return Utils.iterableToCollection(((HomeRepository) (getRepository())).findAll(), HashSet::new);
    }
```

Controller

```
    @GetMapping("/all")
    @ResponseBody
    public GenericResponse getHouses(@RequestParam("id") Long userId) {
        Set<Home> houses = homeService.getHouses(userId);
        return new GenericResponse(
                "houses fetched successfully",
                houses,
                HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }
```

Home

```
public class Home extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "homeAddress_id")
    private Address address;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "properties", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Client> clients = new HashSet<>();

    @Lob
    private byte[] apartmentPicture;
}
```

Client

```
public class Client extends User {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "CLIENT_HOME",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "home_id")
    )
    private Set<Home> properties = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with One to One json loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115021/how-to-deal-with-one-to-one-json-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Jackson 2.6+`, you can use `@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)` on the property you don't want to serialize. So if you want to include the clients when you fetch your houses, put it on the `properties` field in your `Client` class, which will simply ignore that field during serialization. However, I would advise you to decouple your database layer from your representation layer and map every entity to a DTO, that helps you a lot in the long run.

You can read more about the `JsonProperty` annotation [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html).